# duplicate symbol for architecture armv7 error

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, linker-errors, armv7

I'm getting following error after including an external framework and building the project with it. Don't know what to do. Only headers file of the external framework are available to me. All the implementation files (`.m`) are in a `.exe` file so I can't access them.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
    /Users/u311107/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConsumerApp-awxafvfmhvwglmdvoobikahakarp/Build/Intermediates/ConsumerApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/ConsumerApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/u311107/Desktop/Stash/Mall/consumer/KMCSDK.framework/KMCSDK(AppDelegate.o)

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
    /Users/u311107/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConsumerApp-awxafvfmhvwglmdvoobikahakarp/Build/Intermediates/ConsumerApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/ConsumerApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/u311107/Desktop/Stash/Mall/consumer/KMCSDK.framework/KMCSDK(AppDelegate.o)

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18628761/1104126 - This answer helped me

Comment: @Skullz i tried you suggestion but then it gives me a new error as `No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7).`

Comment: [project name]->[target name]->Build Settings->Search "Architectures"->Under the 'Architectures' key click the drop down and select Standard Architectures

Comment: I selected both the option in the drop down menu but still it says the same problem as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like, `KMCSDK.framework` has already declared an `AppDelegate` class, if you can not modify the source code of `KMCSDK.framework` and rebuild it, you should rename `AppDelegate` in your project to fix this problem.

Comment: Ok. So i've renamed the `AppDelegate` class but still the same problem persists.